# How do I sort this array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I have this array:

```
[14, 'S', 12, 'D', 8, 'S', 9, 'S', 10, 'D']
```

I want to sort it in descending order (numbers), but at the same time keep the number with the following letter together. So the result should look like this:

```
[14, 'S', 12, 'D', 10, 'D', 9, 'S', 8, 'S']
```

How can I do this?

I tried to do it this way (five_cards_num is the name of the array):

```
for j in range(4):
    max = five_cards_num[j]
    max_color = five_cards_num[j+1]
    for i in range(j, 5):
        if (five_cards_num[2*i] > max):
            max = five_cards_num[2*i]
            max_color = five_cards_num[2*i+1]
            five_cards_num[2*i] = five_cards_num[j]
            five_cards_num[2*i+1] = five_cards_num[j+1]
            five_cards_num[j] = max
            five_cards_num[j+1] = max_color
```

But I get error:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to turn the list into a list of tuples so you can sort the pairs together, and then flatten it with nested list comprehension afterwards:

```
print([a for i in sorted(zip(five_cards_num[::2], five_cards_num[1::2]), reverse=True) for a in i])
```

This outputs:

```
[14, 'S', 12, 'D', 10, 'D', 9, 'S', 8, 'S']
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Could you please give me a little more explanation on what "a for i in" and "for a in i" does? I've never seen "for" used like this before.

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can refer to [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this simple solution:

```
list(sum(sorted(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]), reverse=True), ()))
```

**Output**:

```
[14, 'S', 12, 'D', 10, 'D', 9, 'S', 8, 'S']
```

Comment: Nice one liner :) @Lev

Comment: @KostadinSlavov Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Again another approach using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a = [14, 'S', 12, 'D', 8, 'S', 9, 'S', 10, 'D']
>>> b = sorted(it.izip(*[iter(a)]*2), reverse=True)
>>> b
[(14, 'S'), (12, 'D'), (10, 'D'), (9, 'S'), (8, 'S')] # you may want to play with a list of tuples (?|!)
>>> list(it.chain(*b))
[14, 'S', 12, 'D', 10, 'D', 9, 'S', 8, 'S']
```